# create an array of the smallest magnitude values from two equal sized numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,-2,3]) 
b=np.array([-2,-1,4])
```

I know how to create an array of the minimum of each pair of entries:

```py
np.minimum(a,b)
array([-2, -2,  3])
```

And how to get an array of the absolute value of the smallest magnitude vales

```py
np.minimum(abs(a),abs(b))
array([1, 1, 3])
```

But what I would like is an array of the smallest magnitude values but retaining the sign of the values, in other words to get

```py
array([1,-1,3])
```

as my output...  I can't think of a python-esque way of doing this in one line, only resorting to long-winded loops and if-thens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.where` with absolute values as conditions and original arrays as return elements:

```
np.where(np.abs(a) > np.abs(b), b, a)
# array([ 1, -1,  3])
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of np.where is the best answer, but I just worked out an alternative solution using a python iteration:

```
np.array([a[i] if abs(a[i])<abs(b[i]) else b[i] for i in range(len(a))])
```

The `np.where` function will be much faster of course.