# How isolate just the smallest magnitude values from an R data frame

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, subset, magnitude

**My Problem**

I have the following (simplified) dataframe `df` :

```
        A    B    C
[1,]    2   -5   20
[2,]  -10   -1   10
[3,]   10  -10    0
```

I want to isolate just the values of the smallest magnitude:

```
[ 2, -1, 0 ]
```

How would I do that?

**What I've Tried**

So far I've just got it to show me what the minimum *absolute* value is per row:

```
  MagMin <- vector()
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){ 
    sub <- df[i,]
    MagMin[i] <- min(abs(df[i,]))
    }
```

Which gives me `[2, 1, 0]`, but obviously, I've lost the signage for what way the smallest value goes.

I found a nice answer to the question in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157772/create-an-array-of-the-smallest-magnitude-values-from-two-equal-sized-numpy-arra), but I can't think how to apply it here!

Comment: r2evans presents a very nice solution to your problem.  Also note that because R is vectorized, the requirement for loop structures, e.g.`for` is greatly reduced.  Study the vectorization functionality of R including the family of `apply` functions.  It will make your coding a lot easier and simpler downstream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
apply(mat, 1, function(z) z[which.min(abs(z))])
# [1,] [2,] [3,] 
#    2   -1    0
```

Walk-through:

- When you want the min-*magnitude*, `min(abs(val))` will return the positive of that, which you know ...

  ```r
  val <- c(-10L, -1L, 10L)
  min(abs(val))
  # [1] 1
  ```
- We can use `which.min(abs(val))` to determine *which* in the vector is the min-*magnitude*, which returns an index on the vector:

  ```r
  which.min(abs(val))
  # [1] 2
  ```
- Using that, we can extract the specific value (pos or neg) based on the min-magnitude:

  ```r
  val[which.min(abs(val))]
  # [1] -1
  ```
- to repeat the operation for each row, we use `apply(mat, 1, ...)`. The `1` is for `MARGIN=1` which means "by row", and the third argument  (`FUN=`) is a function that takes exactly one argument and does something with it; in this case, the first time it's called, `z` is effectively `mat[1,]`, with the values `c(2, -5, 20)`; the second time, it's effectively `mat[2,]` with values `c(-10, -1, 10)`; etc.

---

Data

```r
mat <- structure(list(A = c(2L, -10L, 10L), B = c(-5L, -1L, -10L), C = c(20L, 10L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("[1,]", "[2,]", "[3,]"))
```